# Solaris not seeing FC volume

Tags: raid, storage, solaris, hardware-raid, fibre-channel

We recently replaced a failed controller in an AL connected RAID. I wasn't the one that replaced the controller, but apparently when the new controller was installed something weird happened with the channel IDs/LUNs, but retained the volume configuration. Right now I have it on a single controller, with the channel IDs and LUNs correctly configured, but Solaris isn't seeing the volume (/dev/dsk doesn't have device links for the volumes), even after a boot -r. cfgadm -al shows connected and unconfigured. I tried cfgadm -c c7 configure, but this did not work. fcinfo hba-port shows the connection as offline. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a little unclear about the architecture- what type of controller is it? Local raid card in the server, or standalone shared storage?

Answer (score 1):

Try cycling the port

- cfgadm -c disconnect
- cfgadm -c connect
- cfgadm -c configure